# Convert Generic Method Parameter to Specific Type

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda, expression

Given a generic method `Get<T>` which takes the following parameter...

```
Expression<Func<T,bool>> foo
```

Within that method body I want to test if 'T' is typeof(Stuff) and if yes, then cast it:

```
Expression<Func<Stuff,bool>> boo = (???) foo;
```

The first reaction I expect is "No need to cast it, it is already of type `Stuff` if that was passed in."  But I have found that is not true where method dispatching is concerned!!

So yes I need to test and cast but don't know how.

Below is the context of why and where this is necessary.

I have code like this:

```
public class Stuff {
    public int Alpha;
}

interface ISomething {
    List<T> Get<T>(Expression<Func<T,bool>> lambda);
}

public class Something : ISomething {

    List<T> Get<T>(Expression<Func<T,bool>> expr){
      //...

      //Makes non-recursive call to non-generic 'Get' method.
      //Works as expected.
      Get((Stuff x) => x.Alpha > 10);

      //UH-OH! makes recursive call to Get<T> even when T is typeof(Stuff)!
      //This is where casting is needed!
      Get(expr);

      //...
    }

    List<Stuff> Get(Expression<Func<Stuff,bool>> expr){
       //...
    }
}
```

My intention is to have the generic method `Get<T>` call the non-generic `Get` if the `expr` `LambdaExpression` specifically takes a parameter of type `Stuff`.  But that is not what happens in the above code.

If I run this code...

```
ISomething foo = new Something();
var result = foo.Get((Stuff x) => x.Alpha < 20);
```

...the function called is `Get<T>`.  This is not surprising, even though the non-generic `Get` is a better match, because `Get<T>` is the only available match within the ISomething interface.  So for this is ok.

But once the `Get<T>` method executes, I want the non-generic `Get` to be invoked with the same argument named `expr`.  Given the behavior I'm observing, it looks as though I can only get what I want if I cast the `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` to `Expression<Func<Stuff,bool>>`.  This also assumes I have an test, like `is` or `as`, to confirm it is castable.

How is the type-test done, and how is the cast done?

Is there another way to coerce the more specific and non-generic `Get` method to be called?  Please assume the caller must work through the `ISomething` interface only.

Granted, it would be even more ideal if the non-generic `Get` was called immediately without going through `Get<T>` at all.  But if I'm forced to work through the `ISomething` interface, I don't think that is possible.

FYI, if a way can be found to make this work - it would then provide functionality that is somewhat similar to "[traits - the else-then-if](http://erdani.com/publications/traits.html)" in C++.

Comment: Have you tried using GetType()?

Comment: And could you please explain your use-case a little better? This design seems overly-complicated to me, and I'm positive there is an elegant, object-oriented way to simplify it.

Comment: @rmayer06: added one additional comment and link at the bottom to clarify why this is useful.

Comment: So you don't have control over the interface definition?

Comment: @mayer06: Correct.  Interface is fixed.  Actually, the interface is mine and so technically I could change it...but the whole point is to have a design which allows me to add specializations of implementation without affecting the interface.  Again, vaguely like C++ "Traits."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
public List<T> Get<T>(Expression<Func<T,bool>> expr){
    var expr2 = expr as Expression<Func<Stuff, bool>>;
    if (expr2 != null){
        return Get(expr2) as List<T>;
    }

    //...
}
```

This code makes ReSharper freak out, but it appears to work :)

A better option, if possible, would be to add a non-generic overload to ISomething.

Comment: Unbelievable.  This is exactly the first thing I tried, and found it didn't work.  I see your answer and try it again - it works.  Whatever!  At least it works. :)

Comment: I like the solution :-)  But I do feel sorry for the guy who has to figure out what your code is doing down the road... ;-)